# Preference Screen without XML

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preference, preferencescreen

I want to use preferences, but I don't want to use it in xml.
I used this to find my xml:

```
this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

And this is my .xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="name">
        <ListPreference android:key="name" android:title="Find name" android:summary="Select your name"
        android:defaultValue="2" android:entries="@array/name" android:entryValues="@array/nameValues"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

This works!
But how can I do declare the preferences in my activity .java without the xml file?
Maybe someone can give me a short sample code for my short code.

Thanks.

Comment: @mark: Thanks I also will help other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just could do

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
     preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     Boolean mypref = preferences.getBoolean("mypref_whatever", true);
```

If you need to write a preference you just use an editor

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("mypref_whatever", false);
    editor.commit();
```

This way you don't need an xml at all. Is that what you are looking for?

A.

Answer (score 1):

I have explained how to do this  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942803/is-it-possible-to-create-a-preference-screen-with-preferencefragment-without-usi/19844408#19844408)
this is done by creating a PreferenceScreen programmatically and binding a ListPreference to it, which then will be added to the current PreferenceFragment or Preference activity